# Copying values over a threshold to a new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking to create a macro that will search a column for values over a set threshold, and then copy these values, and some other values in the row, to a table in a different sheet.

I've achieved it using a for loop, however I'm currently using only a small data set (~200 rows) and it needs to work with up to maybe 60000 or so rows, and in my experience for loops tend to become inefficient when using lots of data!

Here's what I have:

```
Sub MondayTable()

Dim ShMonday As Worksheet
Dim ShSummary As Worksheet


Set ShMonday = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Monday Data")
Set ShSummary = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary")

Dim rCount As Integer
Dim AlertRow As Integer
Dim ActionRow As Integer

ActionRow = 17
AlertRow = 17

' Action Level

For rCount = 310 To 550

If ShMonday.Cells(rCount, 12) > 0.5 Then

    ShSummary.Cells(ActionRow, 5) = ShMonday.Cells(rCount, 12)   ' PPV
    ShSummary.Cells(ActionRow, 4) = ShMonday.Cells(rCount, 7)   ' Time

    ActionRow = ActionRow + 1

End If

' Alert Level

If ShMonday.Cells(rCount, 12) > 0.3 And ShMonday.Cells(rCount, 12) < 0.5 Then

     ShSummary.Cells(AlertRow, 3) = ShMonday.Cells(rCount, 12)   ' PPV
     ShSummary.Cells(AlertRow, 2) = ShMonday.Cells(rCount, 7)   ' Time

AlertRow = AlertRow + 1

End If


Next rCount


End Sub
```

Another thing that I would like to add is that the table I'm creating summarises numbers over the thresholds for each day, and currently I'm having a button for each. How can I execute the same function, searching for data on different sheets, where the output goes into adjacent columns in the summary sheet, using just one button?

Also, while I'm here, if a line could be added to the start that clears the current contents of the table that would be a bonus!

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cut down on the iterations your for loop has to go through by first sorting the block of data on the column in question:

```
'declare ranges to leverage Excel's built-in sort capability
Dim DataBlock As Range, SortHeader As Range

'assuming the column header is one row up from the start of the loop and
'the 12th column is the last in the block of data
Set SortHeader = ShMonday.Cells(309, 12)
Set DataBlock = ShMonday.Range(ShMonday.Cells(309, 1), ShMonday.Cells(550, 12))

'sort the data block in descending order
DataBlock.Sort Key1:=SortHeader, Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
```

Then, with a sorted data block, you could exit your for loop once you cross the low threshold:

```
For rCount = 310 To 550

    ' Action level    
    If ShMonday.Cells(rCount, 12) > 0.5 Then
        ShSummary.Cells(ActionRow, 5) = ShMonday.Cells(rCount, 12)   ' PPV
        ShSummary.Cells(ActionRow, 4) = ShMonday.Cells(rCount, 7)   ' Time
        ActionRow = ActionRow + 1
    End If

    ' Alert Level
    If ShMonday.Cells(rCount, 12) > 0.3 And ShMonday.Cells(rCount, 12) < 0.5 Then
        ShSummary.Cells(AlertRow, 3) = ShMonday.Cells(rCount, 12)   ' PPV
        ShSummary.Cells(AlertRow, 2) = ShMonday.Cells(rCount, 7)   ' Time
        AlertRow = AlertRow + 1
    End If

    'Exit the loop
    If ShMonday.Cells(rCount, 12) <= 0.3 Then 
        Exit For
    End If
Next rCount
```

Comment: Ah, sorting the data first was something I hadn't thought of. I'll give that a go. Should save on potentially hundreds of iterations.

Comment: Hey @holmes321, if my answer was satisfactory I'd appreciate you marking it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

'To clear contents use something like this

ShSummary.Columns("C:C").ClearContents
ShSummary.Columns("D:D").ClearContents

'or

ShSummary.Columns("C:D").ClearContents

'For efficiency you could save your ppv value instead of referencing it several times.

Dim ppv

if ppv = "" then 'You can also check if it is blank first and then skip to the end
     rcount = 60000 'or however high it needs to be watch out for the integer limit 
                    'though you are almost there
else
     ppv = cdbl(ShMonday.Cells(rCount, 12))

```
 If ppv > 0.5 Then 'etc....
```

end if

'at the end you can call your second procedure which would eliminate the need for a second button

call otherprocedurename